# Running custom Android system app that uses JNI / NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm writing a system app that uses JNI / C++ code. I have a script that puts it into `system/priv-app` and have been able to run it. However, I get a run-time exception saying

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/priv-app/Launcher/Launcher.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/Launcher/lib/arm, /system/priv-app/Launcher/Launcher.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "lib_MFRC.so`

It works fine if I use it in `/data/app` folder, but not `system/priv-app/Launcher`. **Can anyone help me solve this run-time error?**

Comment: Is seems that for system app that use native libs copying apk to /system/priv-app/ is not enough. It's necessary to reproduce the structure that other systems apps have: /system/priv-app/app/ must contain both app.apk and lib/arm/libnative.so

Comment: @anagaf yes, but the problem is the code for my library doesn't actually produce a .so file that I can copy or I haven't figured it out yet.